# matplotlib contourf plot sparsity whitespace, need interpolation?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, contourf

I have a set of data captured in a pandas data frame which I would like to plot on a contourf plot.  When plotting, I can see much white space in certain areas of the contour which I'm not sure how to fix.  My x-data is semilog.  I'm not sure if some kind of interpolation would help, or if it is someway I am generating my mesh grid and contour itself.  I will attach an image and 2 sets of data frames as examples.

[contourplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT6OA.png)

Data file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13aO1_P0wzLCjZSTIgalXyaR4cdW1_Rh8?usp=sharing

```
import os,sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#dev
import pprint
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)


# start
Data = pd.read_csv('DF.csv',index_col=0)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16,10)
Freqs = Data.iloc[:,0]      # Frequencies for data
angleFullset= ['{:03}'.format(x) for x in [*range(0,360,15)]]   # test set, name of df cols in degrees
angleContour = [[int(x) for x in angleFullset],[int(x) if int(x) < 181 else int(x) - 360 for x in angleFullset]]    # rename colum names to -180 to 180 deg
angleContour[0].append(angleContour[0][0]); angleContour[1].append(angleContour[1][0] - 1)  # append 1 more column for last data set (which is same as first)
idx_180 = angleContour[1].index(180)
angleContour[0].insert(idx_180 + 1,-180); angleContour[1].insert(idx_180 + 1,-180)          # insert another column after 180 to cover -180 case

[X,Y] = np.meshgrid(Freqs,angleContour[1])
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.semilogx()
plt.hlines(0,20,20000,'k',linewidth=1.5)      # zero axis 
plt.vlines(100,-200,200,'k',linewidth=2)      # 100Hz axis
plt.vlines(1000,-200,200,'k',linewidth=2)     # 1kHz axis
plt.vlines(10000,-200,200,'k',linewidth=2)    # 10kHz axis
plt.xlim([85,8000])
plt.ylim([-180,180])
plt.xticks([100,1000,8000],('100','1000','8000'))
plt.yticks(range(-180,181,30))  
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('Angle [deg]')
plt.grid(b=True,which='major'); plt.grid(b=True,which='minor')
plt.title('Contour')

newData = Data.copy()
newData.drop("Freq",axis=1,inplace=True)
newData['001'] = newData['000']                                             # for data from -345 to 0
newData.insert(newData.columns.get_loc('180')+1,'-180',newData['180'])      # for data from -180 to -165
lev_min,lev_max,levels = -70,-19,range(-70,-19,1)

CM = ax.contourf(X,Y,newData.transpose(),cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet,levels=levels,vmin=lev_min,vmax=lev_max)
plt.colorbar(CM,label='Magnitude [dB]',fraction=0.1)

outputFileName = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'Contour.png')
plt.savefig(outputFileName,orientation='landscape',format='png')
plt.clf()
plt.cla()
```

Comment: You're setting color levels, perhaps some data might be outside that range.  But in general, a good normalization of the colors with your data is a good idea, especially if the data isn't linear.  I think matplotlib has ```norm``` as one of the contourf arguments, and you can always make your own custom normalization class. https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize

Comment: Thanks @alvrm for the suggestion.  I tried ```CM = ax.contourf(X,Y,newData.transpose(),cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet,levels=levels,norm=matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=lev_min,vmax=lev_max))``` but the results were unchanged.  At this point I'm pretty sure that the data all falls within the range, but I'm also wondering if some masking may be happening somewhere and how to check it.

Comment: Another point I found is that if I copy my data frame all except 1 column back onto itself, the plot becomes almost fully filled.